# Run methods on different threads

Tags: android, multithreading, twitter4j

I have created an application that uses twitter 4j i am trying to run on different threads to make it faster but i got that errors

```
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5139)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1011)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:493)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:422)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:267)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at a.a.a.StatusListActivity.loadHomeTimeline(StatusListActivity.java:91)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at a.a.a.StatusListActivity.access$0(StatusListActivity.java:84)
08-03 16:02:02.138: E/AndroidRuntime(439):  at a.a.a.StatusListActivity$2.run(StatusListActivity.java:78)
```

here it's my code

```
public class StatusListActivity extends ListActivity{



    private Otweet app;
    private Twitter twitter;
    private OAuthHelper authhelper;
    private LoadMoreListItem headerView;
    private LoadMoreListItem FooterView;
    private StatusListAdapter adapter;
    protected ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    private Handler handler=new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        app=(Otweet)getApplication();
        twitter=app.gettwitter();
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.http.useSSL","false");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if(!app.isAuthorized())
        {
        beginAuthorization();
        }
        else
        {
            if(null==getListAdapter())
            loadHomeTimelineifnotloaded();
        }
    }

    public void beginAuthorization()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(StatusListActivity.this,AuthorizationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void loadHomeTimelineifnotloaded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  progressdialog=ProgressDialog.show(StatusListActivity.this,"Load home timeline","loading");
        Thread LoadHomeTimeline=new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
            loadHomeTimeline();
            handler.post(FinishedLoadingTasks);
            }
        };
        LoadHomeTimeline.start();
    }
    private void loadHomeTimeline()
    {
    try {


        ArrayList<Status> status=twitter.getHomeTimeline();
        adapter=new StatusListAdapter(this, status);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setloadMoreViews();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setSelection(1);


    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-genera ted catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "jj", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

    private Runnable FinishedLoadingTasks=new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finishedLoadinglist();
        }


    };

    public void finishedLoadinglist()
    {
        setloadMoreViews();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setSelection(1);
    //  progressdialog.dismiss();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.equals(headerView))
        {
            headerView.showProgress();
            try {
                headerView.showProgress();
                loadnewerTweets();
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if

            (v.equals(FooterView))
            {
                FooterView.showProgress();
                try {
                    LoadOlderTweets();
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    private void LoadOlderTweets() throws TwitterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FooterView.hideProgress();
    ArrayList<Status> statii=twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging().maxId(adapter.getLastId()));
    adapter.appendOlder(statii);    
    }
    private void loadnewerTweets() throws TwitterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //try {
            headerView.showProgress();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            Thread loadMoreThread=new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                ArrayList<Status> statii = twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging().sinceId(adapter.getFirstId()));
                        Runnable finishedLoadingNewerTask=new LoadNewerResults(statii);
                        handler.post(finishedLoadingNewerTask);
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            };

    //  }
//  catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load home timeline",e);
    //  }



    }

    protected void finishedLoadingNewer(ArrayList<Status> statii)
    {

        adapter.appendNewer(statii);
        headerView.hideProgress();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        getListView().setSelection(1);
    }
    private class LoadNewerResults implements Runnable
    {

        private ArrayList<Status> statii;
        public LoadNewerResults(ArrayList<Status> statii)
        {
            super();
            this.statii=statii;
        }
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finishedLoadingNewer(statii);
        }

    }
    private void setloadMoreViews() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        headerView=(LoadMoreListItem)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.load_more, null);
        headerView.showHeaderText();
        FooterView=(LoadMoreListItem)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.load_more,null);
        FooterView.showFooterText();
        getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);
        getListView().addFooterView(FooterView);
    }



    }
```

I have searched for these errors and i found that i have to run something on the main thread.can someone fix it and explain it to me ?Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all Ui operations need to be done on UI thread so from other threads you can call [runonUithread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update Ui elements from other threads.
But in your case I think you would be better off using [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and update Ui elements in [Onprogressupdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) and [OnpostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on the UI thread to update you status list in loadHomeTimeline. Check out [Activity.runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)